# Date Math in Reporting Services Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, dateadd, date-math

I'm trying to add days to a date and then compare to see if it's outside a range to color code a cell.  It's not working--I think I may be making a simple syntax error.

```
iif(
  (DateAdd("d", CInt(Fields!Days.Value), Fields!Date.Value) < Now), "Red", "White")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra ")" at the end.

=iif((DateAdd("d", CInt(Fields!Days.Value), Fields!Date.Value) < Now), "Red", "White")

Comment: That's true! I hadn't noticed that. I removed the inner parentheses in my own answer but left his extra one on the end. I'll edit my response to reflect that. Good pick-up.

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting your expression with an "=" sign?

```
=iif(
    DateAdd("d", CInt(Fields!Days.Value), Fields!Date.Value) < Now, 
    "Red", "White")
```